# Writing to textfile not working, no text produced

Tags: vb.net

```
PupilID = "\" & PupilID & ".txt"

If Dir$(PupilID) = "" Then
    Dim swpupilinfo As New StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath & PupilID, True)
    swpupilinfo.Close()
End If

If System.IO.File.Exists(filename) = True Then
    readerlinecount = File.ReadAllLines(Dir$(PupilID))
End If

Dim objwritere As New System.IO.StreamWriter(filename, True)
objwritere.WriteLine(quiztaken & " correct answers " & correct & " wrong answers " & wrong & " total mark " & totalmark)
objwritere.Close()
```

This is what I am using to write to the text file, all variables have values but when I open the .txt file it contains nothing.
Not that great at programming just going off what my teacher gave me.

Comment: Please post [mcve], what are ***filename***, ***quiztaken*** etc variables? This example can not be verified since it's not complete. Also please explain what is not working, you are generating two textfiles, are both empty?

Comment: @Esko quiztaken has a integer value which reads the file and tells you which quiz this is. filename is the location of the txt file so the Debug folder. Correct and wrong contain integer values, total mark shows you the total correct answers.

Answer (score 1):

Half of the code you have provided does not seem to relate to the question you have asked? Below is a simple implementation of writing to a text file.

You seem to be using `pupilId` and `fileName` as file path locations which could be causing some confusion?

`StreamWriter` which implements `IDisposable` via `TextWriter`, I recommend making use of it. See below

```
Dim pupilId As Integer = 1
Dim path As String = String.Format("\\{0}.txt", pupilId)

Using sw As New StreamWriter(filePath,True)
   sw.WriteLine("Whatever text you want here")
End Using
```